# How to open an FXML file in Scene Builder after adding an unsupported CheckComboBox control?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, controlsfx

I am developing a JavaFX application using IntelliJ IDEA and Scene Builder. In order to create a combobox with multiple selection I have imported the [controlsfx.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/8.40.10) library to both Scene Builder and my project, planning to use the CheckComboBox control they provide, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26633146/5491105).

When I imported the library to Scene Builder the CheckComboBox control was not among the loaded controls. So I edited the FXML file and inserted it by written code.

Unfortunately, after doing this I can no more open the FXML file in Scene Builder. This error occurs when I try to open it directly from Intellij IDEA:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Idea%20Projects/Danube/src/sample/first.fxml

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:80)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleOpenFilesAction(SceneBuilderApp.java:447)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.handleLaunch(SceneBuilderApp.java:427)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStartGeneric(AppPlatform.java:139)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.AppPlatform.requestStart(AppPlatform.java:106)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.start(SceneBuilderApp.java:371)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Idea%20Projects/Danube/src/sample/first.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2864)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2708)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2932)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2921)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2862)
    ... 27 more
```

When I first run Scene Builder and try to open the file from there, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Idea%20Projects/Danube/src/sample/first.fxml:39

    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:92)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:80)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMDocument.<init>(FXOMDocument.java:95)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.updateFxomDocument(EditorController.java:2370)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.editor.EditorController.setFxmlTextAndLocation(EditorController.java:655)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.DocumentWindowController.loadFromFile(DocumentWindowController.java:386)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenFiles(SceneBuilderApp.java:579)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp.performOpenRecent(SceneBuilderApp.java:272)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.menubar.MenuBarController$21.handle(MenuBarController.java:1188)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.menubar.MenuBarController$21.handle(MenuBarController.java:1183)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1344)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1319)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$7.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1287)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer$7.handle(ContextMenuContent.java:1285)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Idea%20Projects/Danube/src/sample/first.fxml:39

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ControlsFX Error: ControlsFX 8.40.10 requires at least Java Version 8 Update 40
    at impl.org.controlsfx.version.VersionChecker.doVersionCheck(VersionChecker.java:96)
    at org.controlsfx.control.ControlsFXControl.<init>(ControlsFXControl.java:35)
    at org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox.<init>(CheckComboBox.java:113)
    at org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox.<init>(CheckComboBox.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1010)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 54 more
```

Although I have Java Version 8 Update 91...

I would really want to keep using Scene Builder. What could I do about it?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this happen as well when you open first Scene Builder, and load the FXML file from there, instead of opening from IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes, it happens in both ways.

Comment: What is your Scene Builder version?

Comment: It is Version: 2.0-b20.

Comment: Can you upgrade it to Scene Builder 8.2.0? http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/

Comment: Thank you very much, @JoséPereda! That was it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3956070/jos%C3%A9-pereda), I switched to [another version of Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/) and my issue disappeared. I can now use the CheckComboBox control with Scene Builder.